# c++ Creating new LinkedList Class : Clear() method pointer being freed not allocated

Tags: c++, linked-list

I tried to create a new linkedlist class .
the code work & run fine , but still got some error messege .

I know the problem locate in LinkedList::Clear(); method.

I make 2 pointers

P" for locate and deletion (delete p;) ,

And  "savecurrent" to locate where  to delete next ;

an error messege here

```
HelloWorld(25850,0x7fff72537310) malloc: *** error for object 0x100b01030: 
pointer being      freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Heres the code

```
#include "linkedlist.h"
#include "strlib.h"
#include <string>


LinkedList::LinkedList(){
      x_front = NULL;
      x_size =0;
   }

 LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
       ListNode*p = x_front;
       ListNode*savecurrent = x_front;
       for(p ; p != NULL ; p = savecurrent){
            savecurrent = savecurrent->next;
           delete  p;
       }
 }



void LinkedList::add(int value){
               if(x_front == NULL){
                   x_front = new ListNode(value,NULL);
                     }
               else {
                    ListNode *current = x_front;
                    while(current-> next != NULL){
                       current = current -> next;
                        }
                    current->next = new ListNode(value,NULL);
               }
     x_size++;
}


 void LinkedList::clear(){
         ListNode*p = x_front;
         ListNode*savecurrent = x_front;
         for(p ; p != NULL ; p = savecurrent){
                   savecurrent = savecurrent->next;
                   delete p;
                   x_size --;
         }
 }

 string LinkedList::toString() const{
                     string mystring;
                     for(ListNode*p=x_front;p!=NULL;p=p->next){
                     mystring = mystring + " " + integerToString(p->value);
                     }
                     return mystring;
 }


int LinkedList::size() const{
         return x_size;
 }
```

Header .h

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 using namespace std;

struct ListNode{
     int value;
     ListNode* next;

     ListNode(int d,ListNode *n){
         value = d;
         next = n;
     }
 };

 class LinkedList
 {
 public :
     LinkedList();
     ~LinkedList();
     void add(int value);
     void clear();
     int get(int index) const;
     bool isEmpty() const;
     void remove(int index);
     int size() const;
     string toString() const;

 private :
     ListNode* x_front;
     int x_size;
 };

 #endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

Comment: Post the header file also!

Comment: Why are you using `delete []` , it should be only `delete`

Comment: Wow thanks alot !!!   (just removed [] and run still got the same error messege )                                      HelloWorld(25904,0x7fff72537310) malloc: *** error for object 0x100c02cf0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: @user3143047 -- Some advice --I would suggest that you implement the remove() and isEmpty() functions first.  This way, you're removing one node only.  Once you have one node removed correctly, then you implement clear() in terms of remove() and isEmpty().

    `LinkedList::clear() { while (!isEmpty()) remove(0); }`

Comment: @user3143047 -- Also, why is your LinkedList destructor not calling clear() to do the work?  The less "pointer-stuff" you have, the less chance of making a mistake deallocating memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating individual objects (e.g., `new ListNode(value,NULL)`) but you are deleting array objects, e.g., `delete[] p`. The form of allocations has to exactly the form of deallocations. Try to remove the `[]` from the `delete` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb when using `new`.
For every `new` there should be  a `delete` and for every `new []` there should be a `delete []`.

And also, why are you cleaning up all the nodes in the `destructor` as well as it is done in the `clear()` routine already. Keep any one of them.

One suggestion would be to assign the node pointer to `NULL` after destruction. This would prevent the double deletion.